# What is the meaning of "per route basis" in PoolingClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, apache, http

[ThreadSafeClientConnManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html) is deprecated and a new method is introduced [PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html).

The documentation of PoolingClientConnectionManager says

> Manages a pool of client connections and is able to service connection
>   requests from multiple execution threads. Connections are pooled on a
>   per route basis.

**My Question**

What is the meaning of *per route basis* here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the HttpRoute. The HttpRoute is to delineate multiple applications running on the same web server.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoute.html

It is used like below:

```
ClientConnectionRequest connRequest = connMrg.requestConnection(
        new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("localhost", 80)), null);
ManagedClientConnection conn = connRequest.getConnection(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    BasicHttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", "/");
    conn.sendRequestHeader(request);
    HttpResponse response = conn.receiveResponseHeader();
    conn.receiveResponseEntity(response);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        BasicManagedEntity managedEntity = new BasicManagedEntity(entity, conn, true);
        // Replace entity
        response.setEntity(managedEntity);
    }
    // Do something useful with the response
    // The connection will be released automatically 
    // as soon as the response content has been consumed
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // Abort connection upon an I/O error.
    conn.abortConnection();
    throw ex;
}
```

source: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Comment: A little more explanation in simpler words will make the answer useful to broader audience.

Comment: links are broken. what happens if my host will be resolved to a different IPs ? (i am using consul as service discovery)

Answer (score 21):

Put it in simple term, per route means per host you are connecting to.

`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` maintains a maximum limit of connections on a per route basis and in total. Per default this implementation will create no more than 2 concurrent connections per given route and no more 20 connections in total.