# Apache HttpRoute - defining a route

Tags: java, http, routes, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using the Apache `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` to create a pool of connections to difference services on my network. The documentation says that *Connections are pooled on a per route basis*. It is not entirely clear to me what is meant by a *route*.

I found another [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12028635/1491636) question, but the answer is still a little unclear. If we have two applications on the same server, each with multiple REST api's, is each API considered a distinct route?

For example, if we have the following:

```
 http://server1/app1/books
 http://server1/app1/magazines
 http://server1/app2/cars
 http://server1/app2/cars/color/red
 http://server1/app2/cars/color/black/doors/2
```

Would each of the above be considered a single route?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` implements `ConnPoolControl<HttpRoute>`, so we can presume that the routes we are talking about are `HttpRoute`'s.

In the documentation, it's written that `HttpRoute` is

> The route for a request.

One of the constructor of `HttpRoute` is of the form :

```
HttpRoute(HttpHost target, InetAddress local, HttpHost[] proxies, boolean secure, RouteInfo.TunnelType tunnelled, RouteInfo.LayerType layered)
```

Looking at  `RouteInfo.LayerType`, we see :

> The layering type of a route. Plain routes are established by
>   connecting or tunnelling. Layered routes are established by layering a
>   protocol such as TLS/SSL over an existing connection. Protocols can
>   only be layered over a tunnel to the target, or or over a direct
>   connection without proxies.

In conclusion, in this context, the term route should be understood as a network route and not as a mapping from url to controllers as defined by the tag "routes" of your question.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the answer yes or no?

Comment: When the documentation says: *Connections are pooled on a per route basis*, the term *route* has to be understood as network route. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Shoot.  Where can I find the definition?  Route = a +b + c?  All this vagueness is painful.

Comment: that answers to good extent ++1. But network route could vary between requests. Though, I am not 100% sure. But this is not my concern. My concern is, will `http://server:port1/somepath` and  `http://server:port2/somepath` be treated as single route or different.  Please answer. This is imp to me to find.

Comment: actually HttpHost has several contructors, including one based on the URI, so I'm not sure the answer is yes:

HttpHost(HttpHost httphost)
HttpHost(String hostname)
HttpHost(String hostname, int port)
HttpHost(String hostname, int port, Protocol protocol)
HttpHost(URI uri)

Comment: I did a test enabling the logging of apache library at level debug and found out that  routes do not include the path, so I confirm the yes